# How to disable keyboard shortcuts completely from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using Phaser 2.2.2 to develop a typing game and there is method called:

```
game.input.keyboard.addKeyCapture(/*[array of keycodes]*/);
```

This worked with Space(no page scrolling), dot, comma dash(dash with a caused one webpage backward) but didn't work with single quote as I can still open Quick Find with it i.e the browser still detects the shortcut. This method prevents the bubbling state of the key when pressed to propagate to the browser, i.e the browser does not detect a keypress.

[addKeyCapture](http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.6/Phaser.Keyboard.html)

I also found this beautiful typing application which disables completely keyboard shortcuts, like magic: https://typing.io/
No additional configuration or installing addons or plugins.

How can I achieve this in my Phaser game as well? Should I put some third party JS libraries.

Ah and btw is this tool for the job: https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The onkeydown event occurs when the user is pressing a key, you can prevent it using returing false:

Use:

```
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Will I be able to type letter with this, for example ~, ', ., - , Space ?

Comment: Eh, that is not what I am looking for. I need to disable keyboard shortcuts, i.e prevent scrolling when pressing Space, or prevent Quick Find when pressing single quote.

Comment: But space and single quote will become completely unusable? Or I do work before returning false for a specific key?

Comment: for shortcut keys only you need to check using keyCode...sing key pressing will be handles automatically

Comment: But they will become unusable. Yes i know you want points but, cannot use it.

Comment: @ Khara Parmar, will this be able to block [ctrl/command + key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24764626/any-way-to-prevent-disable-ctrl-key-shortcuts-in-the-browser/24764878)?

Answer (score 1):

This is too late, but if you want to block keyboard shortcuts, most shortcuts use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key, and the code to block that key using `jQuery` would be:

```
$("input[name='yourinput']").keypress(function(event) {
    if ( event.keyCode == 17 ) {
         event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

**Note**: key 17 is <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

```
window.onkeydown = function(key){if(key.ctrlKey == true){key.preventDefault()}};
```

Comment: Sorry if it isn't what you are looking for, this is my first answer.