# How to disable ctrl+tab in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm building an Angular application and in my application, I have a feature of selecting multiple texts using Ctrl + mouse click on the word. The problem is if the user will press the Ctrl+ Tab doesn't matter if he has multiple tabs opened or not, the ctrl mouse-up event never fires and if I click on the word without ctrl press it selected the word with the previously selected word also.
Is there any way I can block the Ctrl+Tab hotkey of the chrome browser in JavaScript?

Comment: No, you can't change how the browser works from a webpage. It seems like you should focus on fixing the problem, not trying to break browser behaviour to avoid it.

Comment: listen keypress event then you can find control tab

Comment: short answer: No, you can't. What you could do is listen to keypress. keyCode 9 is the tab.

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari It only detects key-down, not key-up

Comment: @Mario But, if I press Ctrl+Tab event never fire

Comment: you can listen to TAB, but CTRL+TAB is reserved.
What you should do is listen to SHIFT+[KEY]. Or use a library for handling keyboard shortcuts (https://craig.is/killing/mice)
Here is a list with reserved chrome shortcuts (https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en)

Comment: And please use the SEARCH function, before asking general questions.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24764626/any-way-to-prevent-disable-ctrl-key-shortcuts-in-the-browser

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + tab is a browser functionality, there is no way you change the default behavior by your web page.

You can have this functionality if you create your own desktop application.

If you want that, I recommend you: [Electron](https://electronjs.org/)

Comment: then how it works for google drive?